# Sequelize get created record's autoincrement id

Tags: sequelize.js

I have an autoincrement `id` int column. I am trying to retrieve id of a created record during `save` but I am of course sending `DEFAULT` within the insert.

Is it possible to retrieve the id without an additional query?

My attempt is below however, `auditWithAssignedId`'s id stays undefined.

```
void audit.save().then(auditWithAssignedId => {
  console.log('auditWithAssignedId', auditWithAssignedId);
  this.backup(auditWithAssignedId);
});
```

Model

```
AccountAudit.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    account: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    action: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    executedOn: { type: DataTypes.DATE, defaultValue: DataTypes.Now },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    schema: 'AUDITS',
    tableName: 'ACCOUNT',
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: false,
  }
});

export class AccountAudit extends Model<
  InferAttributes<AccountAudit>,
  InferCreationAttributes<AccountAudit>
> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare account: string;
  declare action: AuditAction;
  declare executedOn: CreationOptional<Date>;
}
```

Comment: Please show the model definition

Comment: I've included the model.

Comment: Can you show the content `auditWithAssignedId.get({ plain: true })`?